How to rebase a feature branch on top of another and more updated feature branch in git?
I want to rebase the ERD-662 branch on top of the ERD-595-task-01 branch(which is updated to the base branch named stg-sp-13) to include its updates. How to do that?
I’m planning to follow these steps:
git fetch
git checkout ERD-662
git rebase origin/ERD-595-task-01
(Resolve Any Conflicts)
git add <file>
git rebase --continue
git push --force-with-lease


Sounds sensible. What was the problem? (Was there a problem?). Second and third command can be fused: git rebase origin/ERD-595-task-01 ERD-662
